# How do I update/overwrite a custom toolbox item in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I've managed to successfully implement this [custom TabControl project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition-2). I'm Building this `TabControl` project as a .dll file so I can drag it into my other project's toolbox and view the custom control in the designer but when I wanted to change something in the this custom `TabControl` project, when I rebuild the .dll file and drag it in the toolbox again, it doesn't update the existing custom controls in the designer.

When I ctrl+m1 the variables in the custom control in use, it links to read-only metadata.

Do I need to remove all the custom controls first whenever I make a change or is there a way to "update" existing custom toolbox items that are already in the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this issue in vs2019 and vs2022, and it worked perfectly.

When the `dll` is rebuilt, it does not need to be reloaded into the toolbox.

If the program page that depends on the `dll` is not updated, just rebuild it.

My test environment is **.Net Framework 4.8.**

[image]

If you have any questions about this, please let me know and I will continue to follow up.

Comment: I figured out the issue like an hour after I posted but was too busy to respond, I was not running multiple projects in a single solution. I had a single project that was relying on the .dll file of another solution's project.  In which case it does not update automatically.

To have it update automatically I need to add the custom Control project to the same solution that I'm using the custom control in, and then add a project dependency to the custom Control project (the same way you already have it set up.). (note: and the custom control seems to appear in the toolbox automatically)

Comment: When I add the .dll file alone from a separate solution's project it doesn't count as a dependency which I suppose means that Visual Studio doesn't check if the built .dll has been updated.

Comment: In order to remove older versions of the .dll file from the project I can delete the relevant "reference" from `Refrences` folder, this removes all the custom control classes from the project (also remove the old the toolbox item). And then add the new .dll to the toolbox (note: the reference is added upon adding the Custom Control to the designer form, so you'd need to add a new custom control from the toolbox so that Visual Studio generates a Reference from the toolbox item, then all the custom control classes should exist in the project again )

Comment: Hopefully I explained it well enough for anyone having the same issue.

I'll accept your answer since it's sorta correct for what I want though you could explain how to get your setup (that I need all projects to be in the same solution and that I need to set a project dependency to the custom control project. Maybe also leave a sample project.)

Comment: In fact, in my test, in a separate project, as long as the rebuild can achieve the same result.

Comment: Yeah ,I know. In the way I had it set up originally the custom control project was in a different **solution** entirely.